# Change a value in an img

Tags: javascript

at the the moment i'm doing this:

```
 $('.Zoom').empty()
 $('.Zoom').prepend('<img id="zoom_07" src="Zoom.png" data-zoom-image=' + zoomImageDataUri + '/>');
```

What I want to do is just change the "data-zoom-image=" part. How would I do this, something like:

```
 document.getElementById("zoom_07")."data-zoom-image=""+ zoomImageDataUri +";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't have to worry about escaping/building HTML strings if you use jQuery to create the element:

```
$('.Zoom').empty().prepend($('<img>',{id:'zoom_07', src:'Zoom.png','data-zoom-image':zoomImageDataUri});
```

Second, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with the 2nd bit; your syntax is way off. Try this:

```
$('#zoom_07').attr('data-zoom-image',zoomImageDataUri);
```

You may also utilize the `$.data` method, but I don't think it updates the attribute, just jQuery's internal representation of it.

Comment: +1 for addressing the lack of escaping of `zoomImageDataUri` in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#zoom_07').attr('data-zoom-image', zoomImageDataUri);
```

?

Comment: You could elaborate a little bit and perhaps explain to the OP why this would work or what he is doing wrong. This would improve the quality of the answer I think